# Snakemake tabular config

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm using Snakemake with a tabular configuration. This table is a bunch of rows that I first take out of a very large sample overview. The resulting sample.tsv has a lot of columns. I read the samples file like this, somewhere in my Snakefile:

```
samples = pd.read_table('samples.tsv').set_index('samples', drop=False)
```

When I run snakemake:

```
snakemake --cluster-config cluster.json --cluster "qsub -l nodes={cluster.nodes}:ppn={cluster.ppn}" --jobs 256
```

I get the following error:

`16:51 nlv24077@kiato ~/temp/test_snakemake > run_snakemake.sh
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 6 of /home/nlv24077/temp/test_snakemake/rseqc.smk:
Missing input files for rule bam_stat:
analyzed/I7_index.STAR.genome.sorted.bam`

the strange thing is that `I7_index` is one of the column names in my samples table. Why is it using the column names as sample names?

Below I can show you part of the samples table (I can't show all data publicly):
[image]

Edit:

I was calling the samples like this:

```
rule bcl2fastq:
    input:
        config['bcl_dir']
    output:
        expand([os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz'),
                os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz')],
                sample=samples)
    threads: 6
    shell:
        '''
        # Run bcl2fastq
        ...
```

Whereas I should have used:

```
rule bcl2fastq:
    input:
        config['bcl_dir']
    output:
        expand([os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz'),
                os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz')],
                sample=samples['samples'])
    threads: 6
    shell:
        '''
        # Run bcl2fastq
        ...
```

Thanx JeeYem.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code related to this error? For eg., `rule bam_stat`.

Comment: if `samples` column has the values of interest, are you sure you are using something like `samples['samples']` (or `samples.index.values` to row indices) to obtain them?

Comment: Oh, is that necessary? I thought the idea was that as long as the index is your samples, you are fine and you can even address the metadata just by column name. But I just need to really address a certain column? Then setting the samples as index is also not necessary. How then can I call a metadata column, for example when the samples have different read lengths defined in the sample table? Thanx for your swift reply by the way!

Comment: Ok, so indeed that works, I misunderstood what the samples table was used for, it seems to be pretty simple (one can extract lists from it). Now I wonder how I can address other columns, is it using pure python? Like samples[samples['samples']==sample]['read_length] to get one value? I'll try that at least.

Comment: Please show relevant code. It's not easy to make sense of what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, but you answered my question, I thought I could just use the samples table as input for the samples list, but I have to specify it using samples['samples'] or samples.index.values as you say (it has to be a list, not the entire table). My second remark should probably be a new question. It concerns the use of another column of the samples table to use different input for every sample based on the sample table. Edit: I added what was specifically wrong for clarity

Comment: For your later question, I think your proposed solution would work (correct missing single quote typo though).

Comment: Hi JeeYem, my latter solution does not work, I made it different topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095096/snakemake-and-pandas-synthax-getting-sample-specific-parameters-from-the-sample I can't seem to use {sample} inside pandas syntax.